# preserve html post data in php with javascript

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm writing a php script that takes some c code and tests it against a few test cases.
But since the source code can have single and double quotes along with slashes, my script doesn't get the entire data when passed via a textarea. I'm posting using the .ajax method of jQuery

When I tried, here's what happens

```
$code_string = $_POST['code'];
echo $code_string;
```

the input is

```
int a,b;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
printf("%d",a+b);
```

The jQuery code that posts the data is

```
  $('#submitButton').click(
    function(evt){
    userCode = $('#answer').val();
    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'scripts/php/check_answer.php',
    data : 'code=' + escape( userCode ),
    dataType : 'text',
    success : populateResponseToQuestion
    });

evt.preventDefault;
});
```

and the output is

```
int a,b;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
printf("%d",a b);
```

I want to be able to pass the data to php without anything being trimmed off. In this case the + symbol is lost. With more code, I realize more stuff would be lost or modified.

Comment: Are you outputting `$code_string` into textarea or somewhere ele in the page?

Comment: Look at the page source in the browser. Is the text still trimmed?

Comment: @nikhil I edited my answer and added some explanation regarding JS code you added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post data is preserved, but if you want it display correctly in HTML document you have to use `<br>` for new lines, so function [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) will be helpful. You should also use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or mentioned earlier  [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to avoid problems when posting code with `<` character (it can be interpreted as opening HTML tag).

[+]

As for JavaScript part, you are doing it wrong. Either use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `escape()` or pass object to the `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'scripts/php/check_answer.php',
    data : { "code" : userCode },
    dataType : 'text',
    success : populateResponseToQuestion
});
```

This way jQuery will handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

[htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) is what you're looking for.

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentities($code, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
echo htmlentities($code_string);
```